# Best Developer tools for AEM

Tags: aem

I am a newbiew to AEM. I see that the projects in AEM can be developed using CRXDE Lite, Brackets or Eclipse. As I come from a Java background, I prefer to use Eclipse to develop the AEM projects. I tried to use CRXDE, but did not like as it's not convenient. I believe that all the configurations and everything can be built using Eclipse. I've developed HelloWorld app/component and the same is deployed on AEM. But, I want to add little more to the project like listeners, filters and servlets and so on through **eclipse**. But I do not know how to do it.

Question is:

- Where to find the list of materials to develop the project in AEM using Eclipse apart from HelloWorld Project? (FYI, I've already created and published the project)
- Tutorials to cover the listeners, servlets, DAO and other config changes through **Eclipse**
- What is the best tool to develop AEM Projects.

FYI, I am using AEM 6.2 on Java 1.8 - Luna Eclipse

Comment: Please go through the blog to setup your AEM project : http://www.aemcq5tutorials.com/tutorials/adobe-aem-cq5-tutorials/create-aem-multi-module-project/ and  go through https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/the-basics.html

Comment: @VivekDhiman, As I have mentioned in my post, I have already setup the project in Eclipse and was able to create and publish the project in AEM. I want to move to the next level of adding listeners and servlets and so on.I have already gone thru those links for learning. I am expecting something more from Eclipse point of view.

Comment: We have been developing against the Cloud version of AEM for 2 years.  We use eclipse with the AEM plugin, which unfortunately has no useful function, and the server part cannot even connect to a locally running cloud SDK instance.  As code and component content has to be deployed via code build pipeline, we still have to hand write all the content.XML. if the CRX-DE editor could export the xml, it would save us man months of work.  It takes about 4 minutes to compile and deploy our project to a local aem instance on the fastest HW can buy, which means a LOT of waiting to test 2 lines of code

Answer (score 5):

CRXDE is the only option that you have for component/template related development unless you want to write all the XMLs by yourself (you would know that content/configurations/components are all XML based). CRXDE Lite is a powerful web ide that you need for several purposes during AEM project development and can not be substituted with Eclipse.

Adobe/Sling community provides an addon to Eclipse to ease out the development for AEM projects. You can find details on sling ide [here](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/ide-tooling.html).

You can use Eclipse or IntelliJ for java related development and have the project setup correctly with maven profiles to deploy your code to AEM instance (there is no hot swap of code to work with so you will have to deploy build every-time).

For the resources that you are looking for development, there is no single place to find everything you need. Here are few that you can refer to get references you need -

- [Adobe's content management blog](http://blogs.adobe.com/contentmanagement/)
- [CQ Community blog](http://blogs.adobe.com/cqpost/)
- [WEM Blog](http://www.wemblog.com/) by Yogesh Upadhyay
- [AEM Club](http://adobeaemclub.com/)
- [CQ Ops](http://cq-ops.tumblr.com/)
- [AEM Blog](http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2013/08/in-blog-experiencing-adobe-experience.html) by Sreekanth Choudry Nalabotu, Technical Architect, Adobe Systems

For OSGI related fundamentals you could refer to Enroute OSGI Documentation [here](http://enroute.osgi.org/doc/217-ds.html). It covers most of the topics related to OSGI relevant to AEM development also and then specifics around Enroute OSGi implementation which you could leave.

You could enrol into AEM advanced component development training which also provides for a manual to everything you are looking for to get into quick development of AEM components and java classes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can I say likewise? Eclipse is commonly used to develop the components using Java and it can also be used for JCR configurations (in XML), but CRXDE Lite would be more convenient platform to do the rest of the configurations like adding new property. We may need to use Eclipse and CRXDE Lite side-by-side for AEM development.

Comment: Thats true. However i would keep configs via crxde lite as well, prevents malformed xml and does crx/oak specific formatting when you sync it back to code.